# Convex optimisation

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis

How should I read the following:

$\max \left\{0, g_i(x_i)\right\}^2 = 0, \forall i = 1, 2, ..., m$

from the paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1610.02967.pdf.

Is it:

- The square of the elements in the set, thereafter taking the max of the result; or
- The max is calculated first and then the square of the result?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The max is calculated first and then the result gets squared.